# How to place multiple plots on top of each other (or along the x-axis) in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to make a graph in R, something like this

[image]

Where plot 1, 2, and 3 are are at specified markings along the x-axis.

Noting an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288194/plot-inside-a-plot), I think this can be done using the `grconvertX` function with `fig`, but I can't seem to get the code I wrote to plot more than one of the subplots. Here is the toy data and code.

```
  #example
  #main plot variables
   x = seq(0,1, by=.1)
   y = (x/(.2+x))
   plot(x,y, type='b')

  #subplot variables
   xlocations = c(.2,.6,.8)
   nXticks = length(xlocations)

  for(i in 1:nXtick){
    xloc = xlocations[i]
    xRad = .05
    par(fig = c(grconvertX(c(xloc-xRad, xloc+xRad), from="user", to="ndc"),
                grconvertY(c(0, 0.1), from="user", to="ndc")),
        mar = c(0,0,0,0),
        new = TRUE)
    plot(1:10,1:10, axes=F, xlab='', ylab=''); box();
  }
```

Comment: Is this not the same post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288194/plot-inside-a-plot or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896439

Comment: `ggvis` "embedded plots" may be what you are looking for. Here are examples : [visualize complex data with subplots](https://www.r-bloggers.com/visualize-complex-data-with-subplots/).

Comment: The `grid` package is also suited for this job, see e.g. http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n3/zhou.pdf for an introduction

Comment: @zx8754 it is very similar but not a duplicate, since that question does not specify the location of the internal plot, and that aspect of the question is the central point of this one. In addition the answers do not explain this part of the question above. While grconvertX, answer seems like this is possible, it throws errors when the arguments are modified.

Comment: I see, so if you have 1,2,3,4 on Xaxis, then you would need 4 subplots on top of each number on X?

Comment: @zx8754 yes, exactly

Comment: @PaulRougieux subplots no longer works for later versions of R, for what I can tell "package ‘ggsubplot’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)"

Comment: @MHH, yes embedded plots might provide the functionality that you want and [it is supposed to replace faceting in ggvis](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/0.1/ggplot2.html). But it seem to be still under development according to [this github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/442) and to [ggvis layers](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.html): "a future major release [...] will add support for facetting/subplots." Sorry I had this at the back of my mind and didn't know it wasn't available yet.